# How to retrieve a parameter from DownloadDataAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, webclient

Using WebClient in WPF app, the following code works fine, when an image is downloaded an event fire correctly.

I need to pass some parameters to `ImageDownloadCompleted` in order to specifically know which image has been just downloaded.

Using [`webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url), url);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I cannot get the result wanted.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: Basically I would use this parameters to order in an array the images resulted. If very is another way to achieve this, please let me know.

```
 private void DownloadAndPrintImagesAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += ImageDownloadCompleted;
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url), url); // I want to pass url
        }
    }

    private void ImageDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {

            // I need to get url here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `UserState` property of the `DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs` argument:

```
private void ImageDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        var url = (string)e.UserState;
        ...
    }
}
```